# Delete all occurrences of a char from linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, char

I am trying to delete the `char` from the linked list, but I am getting a null pointer error when I return the object. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
public class Answer implements QuestionInterface {
@Override
public SchNode func(SchNode head, char ch){
    SchNode temp=head,temp1;

    while(temp!=null){
        if(temp.ch==ch){
                head=head.nextNode;
        }
        else if(temp.nextNode.ch==ch){
            temp1=temp.nextNode;
            while(temp1.ch==ch){
                temp1=temp1.nextNode;
            }
            temp.nextNode=temp1.nextNode;

        }
        temp=temp.nextNode;

    }
    return head;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: maybe you pass null values to your method

Comment: post exception trace and try to debug on your own